# PHP Array issue - not looping through foreach

Tags: php

Thanks everyone, question answered!  If anyone is interested, the updated function is as follows, all other code remains the same:

```
function fetch_questions($page) {
global $link;
$proc = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT * FROM tquestions_cwh WHERE page = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($proc, "i", $page);
mysqli_stmt_execute($proc);


$rowq = array();
stmt_bind_assoc($proc, $rowq);

// loop through all result rows
//  while ($proc->fetch()) {
    //  print_r($rowq);
//      $rows[]=$rowq;
//  }

while ($proc->fetch())
{
    foreach($rowq as $key=>$value )
    {
        $row_tmb[ $key ] = $value;
    } 
    $rows[] = $row_tmb; 
}

mysqli_stmt_close($proc);
mysqli_clean_connection($link);
return($rows);
```

}

Ok,

Here is the code:

```
function fetch_questions($page) {
    global $link;
    $proc = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT * FROM tquestions_cwh WHERE page = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($proc, "i", $page);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($proc);


    $rows = array();
    stmt_bind_assoc($proc, $rowq);

    // loop through all result rows
    while ($proc->fetch()) {
        //  print_r($rowq);
        $rows[]=$rowq;
    }

    mysqli_stmt_close($proc);
    mysqli_clean_connection($link);
    return($rows);
}
```

I then add this to a php variable, like so:

```
$qs = fetch_questions($page);
```

I then loop through is, like so:

```
foreach($qs as $value){
                echo "<tr>".$value['qnum']." is the questions number and the question text is ".$value['qtext'].". The page and q values are ".$value['page']." and ".$value['questions']." respectively.</tr>";
```

The output, however is this:

```
8 is the questions number and the question text is I know how what I do fits into my team's objectives. The page and q values are 1 and q8 respectively.8 is the questions number and the question text is I know how what I do fits into my team's objectives. The page and q values are 1 and q8 respectively.8 is the questions number and the question text is I know how what I do fits into my team's objectives. The page and q values are 1 and q8 respectively.8 is the questions number and the question text is I know how what I do fits into my team's objectives. The page and q values are 1 and q8 respectively.8 is the questions number and the question text is I know how what I do fits into my team's objectives. The page and q values are 1 and q8 respectively.8 is the questions number and the question text is I know how what I do fits into my team's objectives. The page and q values are 1 and q8 respectively.8 is the questions number and the question text is I know how what I do fits into my team's objectives. The page and q values are 1 and q8 respectively.8 is the questions number and the question text is I know how what I do fits into my team's objectives. The page and q values are 1 and q8 respectively.
```

Which is not what I want, for information purposes, the array using the print function looks like this:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [questions] => q8
                [qnum] => 8
                [qtext] => I know how what I do fits into my team's objectives
                [page] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [questions] => q8
                [qnum] => 8
                [qtext] => I know how what I do fits into my team's objectives
                [page] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [questions] => q8
                [qnum] => 8
                [qtext] => I know how what I do fits into my team's objectives
                [page] => 1
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [questions] => q8
                [qnum] => 8
                [qtext] => I know how what I do fits into my team's objectives
                [page] => 1
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [questions] => q8
                [qnum] => 8
                [qtext] => I know how what I do fits into my team's objectives
                [page] => 1
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [questions] => q8
                [qnum] => 8
                [qtext] => I know how what I do fits into my team's objectives
                [page] => 1
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [questions] => q8
                [qnum] => 8
                [qtext] => I know how what I do fits into my team's objectives
                [page] => 1
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [questions] => q8
                [qnum] => 8
                [qtext] => I know how what I do fits into my team's objectives
                [page] => 1
            )

    )
```

Clearly it's not looping through and displaying each row as it should...any advice?

Homer.

Comment: What are those actual 8 entries in the database?

Comment: Curious, could you please add a dump of the $qs array using: echo var_export($qs,true) ?

Comment: Please provide your need clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the [manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) and find this may help you:

```
/*
while ($proc->fetch()) {         
    //  print_r($rowq);         
    $rows[]=$rowq;         
}
*/
while ($proc->fetch())
{
    foreach($rowq as $key=>$value )
    {
        $row_tmb[ $key ] = $value;
    } 
    $row[] = $row_tmb; 
}
```

**quote:** The problem is that the `$rowq` returned is reference and not data. So, when you write  `$row[] = $rowq`, the `$row` will be filled up with the last element of the dataset.

Comment: @SpawnCxy - THANK YOU!  I made a slight alteration to your code to read as above in the edited questions.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm not that familiar with the procedural style of mysqli so I'm not sure if this is your problem or not. However, it seems to me that you've set $proc to be the result of mysqli_prepare but [according to the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php), this function returns true or false. You've then used $proc as the first parameter for mysqli_stmt_bind_param() but, again [according to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), this parameter should be the return of mysqli_stmt_init() which I assume is $link. In fact, wherever you have used $proc as a parameter, you should instead use $link.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is more, but the markup is wrong: you're missing opening and closing `<td>`. The output you posted seems complete, it just appears all in one line. Try:

```
foreach($qs as $value) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$value['qnum']." is the questions number and the question text is ".$value['qtext'].". The page and q values are ".$value['page']." and ".$value['questions']." respectively.</td></tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_stmt_fetch manual says:

> Note: Note that all columns must be bound by the application before calling mysqli_stmt_fetch().

Maybe for a `SELECT *` query you should use `mysqli_stmt_store_result` and `mysqli_stmt_result_metadata` functions to get all columns.